# Can't share object from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to share an object array `posts.shoppingCart` through controllers. Inside `MainCtrl`
this expression works `$scope.cart = posts.shoppingCart;` but on `AuthCtrl` doesn't. My dummy data appear without problem.

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url : '/home',
            templateUrl : '/home.html',
            controller : 'MainCtrl',
            resolve : {
                postPromise : ['posts',
                    function(posts) {
                        return posts.getAll();
                    }]

            }
        }).state('login', {
            url : '/login',
            templateUrl : '/login.html',
            controller : 'AuthCtrl',
            onEnter : ['$state', 'auth',
                function($state, auth) {
                    if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                        $state.go('home');
                    }
                }]

        }).state('register', {
            url : '/register',
            templateUrl : '/register.html',
            controller : 'AuthCtrl',
            resolve : {
                postPromise : ['posts',
                    function(posts) {
                        return posts.getShoppingCart();
                    }]

            },
            onEnter : ['$state', 'auth',
                function($state, auth) {
                    if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                        $state.go('login');
                    }
                }]

        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');
    }]);


app.factory('posts', ['$http', 'auth',
    function($http, auth) {
        var o = {
            posts : [],
            shoppingCart : []
        };

        o.getAll = function() {
            return $http.get('/catalog').success(function(data) {
                angular.copy(data, o.posts);
            });
        };

        o.getShoppingCart =  function() {
            return o.shoppingCart;
        };

        return o;
    }]);



app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts','auth',
    function($scope, posts, auth) {

        $scope.posts = posts.posts;
        $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
        //setting title to blank here to prevent empty posts

        $scope.sum = 0;
        if ($scope.sum === 0) {
            $scope.isDisabled = true;
        }

        $scope.cart = posts.shoppingCart;
        var sum;
        $scope.addPost = function(post) {
            console.log(post);
            $scope.cart.push({title: post.title, cost: post.cost});
            var sum = parseInt($scope.sum,10) + parseInt(post.cost, 10);

            $scope.sum = sum;
            $scope.isDisabled = false;
        };
    }]);

app.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'posts', 'auth',
    function($scope, posts, $state, auth) {
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
        $scope.cart = [
            {title:'Jani',cost:'Norway'},
            {title:'Hege',cost:'Sweden'},
            {title:'Kai',cost:'Denmark'}
        ];//posts.shoppingCart;

        $scope.register = function() {
            console.log($scope.user);
            auth.register($scope.user).error(function(error) {
                $scope.error = error;
            }).then(function() {
                $state.go('home');
            });
        };

        $scope.logIn = function() {

            auth.logIn($scope.user).error(function(error) {
                $scope.error = error;
            }).then(function() {
                $state.go('home');
            });
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
['$scope', '$state', 'posts', 'auth',
function($scope, posts, $state, auth) {
```

$state and posts are mixed up...

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I didn't know they had to be in the same order. It now works!